# Ways to generate realistic looking low poly tree from detailed tree model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, geometry

I'd like to generate lots of trees in an animated scene. Some of the scenes will be seen relatively close up. It takes too much time to generate detailed trees in the animation. I'm looking for a better way to convert a detailed tree model into a low poly tree model. The simplified approach of using two plane does not produce satisfactory results.

[image: viewing a simplified tree]

---

**Details**

Starting with a tree model generated from the sapling add-on, a detailed tree is model is generated.

[image]

This model is too expensive to use in an animation.

Using two planes with renderings of the tree, a model like this is created.

[image]

This model generates an animation like this as the camera angle changes.

[image: viewing a simplified tree]

This approach is relatively inexpensive, but the results are not really satisfactory. **Are there other, better approaches to convert a detailed tree model into something which can be rendered quickly?**

If it makes any difference, I'm specifically interested in evergreen trees as viewed from ground level.

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtUS8QTsVZA

Comment: I don't think that'll cut it for what he wants, while it is a cool technique it is not meant for close ups. I'd suggest picking a branch and baking that into a branch plane, then instantiating that branch across the main branches, tough I cannot be certain what level of fidelity you want. you could also bake the tree to a cylinder type object and add a few branches and leaves to break the silhouette. It all depends on how close/far the tree is from the camera and how much rotation you have in your shot.

Comment: Since you are doing this in blender sapling, just dont generate high res trees and use branches as textures instead of leaves.

Now if you had an already premade model that you bought? You're out of luck, there is no fast, automatic way to generate LOD (level of detail) models for trees.